# Hashbang for Gnome .desktop files

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, gnome

I'd like to be able to add a `#!` comment at the top of my `.desktop` file so that if it has execute permissions and is executed, it'll actually run. However, I don't know what the interpreter for `.desktop` files is, so I don't know which `/usr/bin/` file to write in the hashbang. Any ideas?

---

**Edit:**

So far, I've made a small bash script, `execdesktop`, that can execute desktop files:

```
`sed -nr 's/Exec=(.*)$/\\1/p' $1`
```

If I then add the following to my `.desktop` files:

```
#!/usr/bin/execdesktop
```

Then it runs fine. This method works, but I'd prefer not to have to use it since it requires the installation of execdesktop.

Comment: Unless you have created a package which installs `execdesktop` using your system package manager (`dpkg`? RPM? `emerge`? etc) the script  should probably be in `/usr/local/bin`, not in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use `xdg-open` for your shebang, as in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
```

This won't cause any trouble because `#` starts comments also in `.desktop` files.

Comment: Interesting, though xdg-open seems to want to open all of my .desktop files in gedit instead of actually launching them.

Comment: @Reinderien: have you associated `.desktop` files to `gedit`? What does `xdg-mime query default application/x-desktop` return?

Comment: @ninjalj It returns nothing (blank).

Comment: @Reinderien: it seems `gnome-open` is oblivious to `application/x-desktop`, and ends up calling the handler for its superclass `text/plain`.

Comment: @Reinderien: you may use `kfmclient exec` instead of `xdg-open`, if you don't mind pulling in lots of Qt/KDE libraries.

Comment: @ninjalj I'll take your word for it. Unfortunately it seems the short answer is that "there's no easy answer".

Comment: @Reinderien: anyway, you should be able to use `#!/bin/sed -ne s/^Exec=//e` as your shebang line.

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343896 https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307172

Comment: @ninjalj The xdg-open issue (opens in gedit) is due to a bug in gnome. Still there is a workaround. Please see my answer to the same question at [askubuntu] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal)

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Desktop files are not intended to be executed EVER.  The fact that in some machines xdg-open MIGHT work is just a question of the association of files, but it's still wrong.  Don't run .desktop files, don't make them executable.

Comment: @Marga Materola so are you meant to use them to launch programmes?  When I install programmes that try and give me a launcher I get a desktop file.   When I open it, it opens in gedit.

Answer (score 7):

Just to be explicit, Ignacio is correct [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020161/4117209) in that *.desktop* files should not be directly executed. It is possible (as you discovered), but unwise.

On another note, do not use `xdg-open`. It might just happen to work if there is a correctly associated mime-type, but this is not reliable.

You should use `gtk-launch`. It is used as follows:

```
gtk-launch APPLICATION [URI...]
gtk-launch app-name.desktop
gtk-launch app-name
```

Here is the man entry:

> NAME
>
> ```
>    gtk-launch - Launch an application
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    gtk-launch [APPLICATION] [URI...]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    gtk-launch launches an application using the given name. The
>    application is started with proper startup notification on a default
>    display, unless specified otherwise.
>
>    gtk-launch takes at least one argument, the name of the application to
>    launch. The name should match application desktop file name, as
>    residing in /usr/share/application, with or without the '.desktop'
>    suffix.
>
>    If called with more than one argument, the rest of them besides the
>    application name are considered URI locations and are passed as
>    arguments to the launched application.
> ```

Please note that `gtk-launch` requires the *.desktop* file to be installed (i.e. located in */usr/share/applications* or *$HOME/.local/share/applications*).

So to get around this, we can use a hackish little bash function that temporarily installs the desired `.desktop` file before launching it. The "correct" way to install a *.desktop* file is via `desktop-file-install` but I'm going to ignore that.

```
launch(){
    (
    # where you want to install the launcher to
    appdir=$HOME/.local/share/applications

    # the template used to install the launcher
    template=launcher-XXXXXX.desktop

    # ensure $1 has a .desktop extension, exists, is a normal file, is readable, has nonzero size
    # optionally use desktop-file-validate for stricter checking
    # if ! desktop-file-validate "$1" 2>/dev/null; then
    if [[ ! ( $1 = *.desktop && -f $1 && -r $1 && -s $1 ) ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: you have not supplied valid .desktop file" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    # ensure the temporary launcher is deleted upon exit
    trap 'rm "$launcherfile" 2>/dev/null' EXIT

    launcherfile=$(mktemp -p "$appdir" "$template")
    launchername=${launcherfile##*/}

    if cp "$1" "$launcherfile" 2>/dev/null; then
        gtk-launch "$launchername" "${@:2}"
    else
        echo "ERROR: failed to copy launcher to applications directory" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    exit 0
    )
}
```

You can use it like so (and also pass along additional arguments or URIs if you want):

```
launch ./path/to/shortcut.desktop
```

---

Alternatively, I wrote an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/664272/335327) that outlines all the ways to launch *.desktop* files. It offers some alternatives to `gtk-launch` that may help.

Comment: Upvoted on techical merit; but the correct answer which should be accepted is the one by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't one; .desktop files aren't intended to be executed. Run the executable given in the `Exec` key instead.

Comment: They're executed one way or another. There's absolutely no way to invoke a .desktop file from the command line? That doesn't seem very linux-like...

Comment: Desktop files are NOT executed.  The line inside them that has an executable command line is the one that gets executed.  The rest of the file is parsed by the Desktop Environment.

Comment: The problem is that in my case the script mentioned in the Exec attribute works but the desktop file doesn't work only under Ubuntu (it works on Mageia). That's why it makes sense to open a desktop file in command line so that it executes the command the same way that the operating system does.